# Collision Detection Glitches

Tags: java, lwjgl

Thanks in advance. I am trying to make a scrolling 2d game with perfect collision detections on the corners of the player. The problem I am having is that if you go left or down on a wall, it works just fine, but on the right or up, it seems to infinitely detect collisions and glitch you to a corner.

I have tried resetting the motion, reverting to old location, subtracting pixels from the position after the translation, and also changing the variables.

```
package me.Rigidity.Apocalypse;

public class Entity extends Tile {

    private float x, y, xm, ym;

    public Entity(String name, float r, float g, float b, float x, float y, float size) {
        super(name, r, g, b);
        this.size = size;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void move(float x, float y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }
    public void position(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void factor(float x, float y) {
        this.xm *= x;
        this.ym *= y;
    }

    public void motion(Map map) {
        motionX(map);
        motionY(map);
    }
    public void motionX(Map map) {
        x += xm;
        if (collision(map)) {
            if (left(map)) {
                x = rightX();
            }
            if (right(map)) {
                x = leftX();
            }
        }
    }
    public void motionY(Map map) {
        y += ym;
        if (collision(map)) {
            if (top(map)) {
                y = bottomY();
                return;
            }
            if (bottom(map)) {
                y = topY();
            }
        }
    }

    public void motion(float x, float y) {
        xm += x;
        ym += y;
    }
    public float x() {
        return x;
    }
    public float y() {
        return y;
    }
    public void x(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void y(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public float xm() {
        return xm;
    }
    public float ym() {
        return ym;
    }

    public Tile bottomleft(Map map) {
        return map.getAbsoluteTile(leftX(), bottomY());
    }
    public Tile bottomright(Map map) {
        return map.getAbsoluteTile(rightX(), bottomY());
    }
    public Tile topleft(Map map) {
        return map.getAbsoluteTile(leftX(), topY());
    }
    public Tile topright(Map map) {
        return map.getAbsoluteTile(rightX(), topY());
    }
    public int leftX() {
        return (int)(((int)(x/Tile.BASIC.size()))*Tile.BASIC.size()+Tile.BASIC.size()-size);
    }
    public int rightX() {
        return (int)(((int)(x/Tile.BASIC.size()))*Tile.BASIC.size()+Tile.BASIC.size());
    }
    public int topY() {
        return (int)(((int)(y/Tile.BASIC.size()))*Tile.BASIC.size()+Tile.BASIC.size());
    }
    public int bottomY() {
        return (int)(((int)(y/Tile.BASIC.size()))*Tile.BASIC.size()+Tile.BASIC.size()-size);
    }
    public boolean top(Map map) {
        return topleft(map) instanceof Solid || topright(map) instanceof Solid;
    }
    public boolean bottom(Map map) {
        return bottomleft(map) instanceof Solid || bottomright(map) instanceof Solid;
    }
    public boolean left(Map map) {
        return topleft(map) instanceof Solid || bottomleft(map) instanceof Solid;
    }
    public boolean right(Map map) {
        return topright(map) instanceof Solid || bottomright(map) instanceof Solid;
    }
    public boolean collision(Map map) {
        return bottomleft(map) instanceof Solid || topleft(map) instanceof Solid || bottomright(map) instanceof Solid || topright(map) instanceof Solid;
    }

}
```

There is no error message, however the result isn't as expected on the right or top collision. Left and bottom work as expected with clean collision, as well as the sliding motion.

Comment: If you need more code or information, let me know.

Comment: My best advice to you is to write a test for the scenario that is not working. So you can debug your code and see where it is behaving different then what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you possibly give an example in the form of an answer? I am new to debugging and honestly quite bad at it.